# Gitlab badge is not detected

Tags: gitlab

I cannot fully figure out how can I ad a custom badge to my gitlab repository. I have created an svg using Python anybadge. See the full script:

```py
import anybadge

thresholds = {2:'red',4:'orange',6:'green'}
badge = anybadge.Badge('pylint',2.22, thresholds=thresholds)
badge.write_badge('pylint.svg')
```

I have placed this `pylint.svg` to my project directory.

In my Gitlab, I have went to create a new badge:

Under the Link, I have entered the following information:

```
https://xxx-test.test.lt/%{project_path}
```

Under the Badge image URL

```
https://xxx-test.test.lt/%{project_path}/pylint.svg
```

My repository link is as following:
https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines

But the .svg does not seem to be detected:
[image]

I can see that other guides suggests adding svg badges via the artifacts. For example here:
https://medium.com/@iffi33/adding-custom-badges-to-gitlab-a9af8e3f3569

But I do not fully understand what is the purpose of adding the badges to the artifacts? Why can I not simply access to .svg that are stored in my project directory?

I would highly appreciate if someone could clarify how can I simply display an .svg that I keep inside the project.

**UPDATE**

I have even tried to place it as an artifact. I can access it via Gitlab :
[image]

As you can see from above, the `pylint.svg` can be accessed via URL:
`https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines/-/jobs/871/artifacts/file/test/pylint.svg`

However, if I try to copy paste this URL to the Badge image URL it will still not show up:
[image]

**UPDATE2**

I have also tried official Gitlab method:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/badges.html#customize-badge-image

They are suggesting to use:

> Using placeholders, here is an example badge image URL referring to a raw image at the root of a repository:

But for my repository, the raw does not even exist:
[image: https://xxx-test.test.lt/embeded-programmers/Embedded-FW-Guidelines/-/raw]

How complicated can it be to add a simple svg to the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

It turns out the correct method is to use the raw as has been shown in the documentation. I have got it to work using the below Badge image URL for my project:

[https://xxx-test.test.lt/%{project_path}/-/raw/main/test/pylint.svg](https://xxx-test.test.lt/%%7Bproject_path%7D/-/raw/main/test/pylint.svg)